# Keep Bootstrap submenu open when page is active

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrao in combination with wordpress and I was wondering if is it possibe to make a bootstrap submenu stay open when the current page is in a submenu item.

I think this can be achieved using javascript but I already made some efforts to make it work with out really a proper solution.

For example I have a menu Like this
ABOUT
  - Company
  - Packaging Benefits
  - Design

and I want the sub menu to stay open when I select any of the submenu page

I think it will be tricky to post the whole code but so far this is what I have done

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<title>
  Company | </title>
  <meta name="description" content="Aliquam lobortis. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue"/>

  <meta name="keywords" content="Company" />


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- fancybox -->
    <link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css' rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.1.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  <body>
     <div id="all">
                      <div id="nocover"></div>


   <section id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <a href="#" id="indexlogo" title="" class="img-responsive">
           <h1 class="sr-only">#</h1>
          </a>
        </div>


        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu-toggle">
                    <div class="menu-mainmenu-container"><ul id="menu-mainmenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-59"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">ABOUT US <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="menu-item--6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item active menu-item--6"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item--7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item--7"><a href="#">Packaging Benefits</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item--8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item--8"><a href="#">Design</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </section>







              <section id="content" class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">

                                        <div id="maincontent">
                                        </div>
              </div>
          </div><!-- // end row -->
      </section>
      <!-- // end section maincontent -->

         </div><!-- //end all -->
        <footer id="footer">

      </footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load Custom javascripts -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://gypthirtynine.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/39-22/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {



</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
opacity: 0;
-moz-transition:    all 1000ms ease;
-webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
-o-transition:      all 1000ms ease;
-ms-transition:     all 1000ms ease;
transition:         all 1000ms ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
}

#main-menu-toggle li a{

}
#main-menu-toggle li {
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
}
#main-menu-toggle li .caret {
display:none;
}
#main-menu-toggle li a{
display:inline-block;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-left:0px;
background:none;
background-image:url(img/tilt.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#main-menu-toggle li a{
color:#fff;
}
#main-menu-toggle li a:hover{
color:#00aeef;
}


/* submenu */
#main-menu-toggle li ul{
/*display:block;*/
height:50px;
z-index:9999 !important;

}

#main-menu-toggle li ul li a{
display:inline-block;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left:0px;
background:url(img/tilt.png) no-repeat right 4px !important;
background-size:25% !important;


}

#main-menu-toggle li ul {
z-index:9999 !important;
width:500px;
background:none;
box-shadow:none;
}

#main-menu-toggle li ul:before {
content:" ";
position:absolute;
top:-40px;
left:-30px;
background:url(img/tiltbig.png) no-repeat 0 0;
height:80px;
width:59px;
z-index:-9999 !important;
cursor:pointer;
}

#main-menu-toggle li ul li{
float:left;
}

#main-menu-toggle li ul li a{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
color:#00aeef;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's help you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert(jQuery('#menu-mainmenu').find('.current-menu-item').text());
 
 jQuery('#menu-mainmenu').find('.current-menu-item').closest('.current-menu-parent').children('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<body>
     <div id="all">
                      <div id="nocover"></div>


   <section id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <a href="#" id="indexlogo" title="" class="img-responsive">
           <h1 class="sr-only">#</h1>
          </a>
        </div>


        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu-toggle">
                    <div class="menu-mainmenu-container"><ul id="menu-mainmenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-59"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">ABOUT US <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="menu-item--6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item active menu-item--6"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item--7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item--7"><a href="#">Packaging Benefits</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item--8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item--8"><a href="#">Design</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </section>







              <section id="content" class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">

                                        <div id="maincontent">
                                        </div>
              </div>
          </div><!-- // end row -->
      </section>
      <!-- // end section maincontent -->

         </div><!-- //end all -->
        <footer id="footer">

      </footer>


 </body>
```

Comment: Ok your script alerts me for the current page but how can I make the parent element to stay open?

Comment: Ok. Just copy my script and add in your code. above snippet result can't display output it's work on full screen. So please check on full screen.